# What DLL to import to use C++ cout manually?

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, x86, cout

What DLL should I import to use cout manually?

I have searched the exports from MSVCRT.DLL and CRTDLL.DLL, but they don't contain cout or cin.

I found something like "?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A" inside MSVCIRT.DLL.

I want to know how to do it manually mainly to compile by hand and to implement my own compiler functions.

Comment: That’s the one. C++ has “mangled” names with type information. But what do you mean “manually”?

Comment: Import (with import tables), load parameters and call in assembly (NASM, GAS, MASM, FASM).

Comment: Also what version are you using. Apparently the libraries have been refactored so the c++ stuff should now be found in `msvcpXX.dll`. In general it makes little sense to invoke `cout` from asm though. Write low level stuff in asm if needed, leave high level stuff such as i/o to C++ code.

Comment: The current version of `std::cout` is a template, so it's quite likely a great deal of it is in headers, not a DLL. What you've found looks to me like an ancient (early 1990s) artifact from when `std::cout` had the type `ostream_withassign`.

Comment: @Jester I would use MSVCP600.DLL by default for compatibility with Windows 98 unless I find a newer version that works under it.

Comment: Why do you think that it is contained in the dynamic library and not statically linked?

Comment: MSVCP60.DLL and MSVCP60D.DLL (d for Debug) seem to be the correct names under Windows 98.

Comment: `std::cout` is an `std::ostream` instance. Not sure how to call it. Anyway this whole *C++* / *ASM* bridge seems a bit unnatural as it skips the *C* intermediary layer . I guess there's a higher chance of success with *printf* like functions.